# How to use $lookup in Angular2-Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular2-meteor

I get this error when using $lookup operator in angular2-meteor:

> Exception from sub tasks id bAJHF7MZzEidGBZ63
>
> ```
> Error: Exception while polling query
> ```

```
{
    "collectionName": "tasks",
    "selector": {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "projects",
            "localField": "project._id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "proj"
        }
    },
    "
    " options ": {
        "transform ": null
    }
}:
```

unknown top level operator: $lookup

When I query directly using robomongo I get the result.

```
versions:
Mongo 3.2.6
angular2-meteor: 0.7.0
Meteor 1.4.2.3
```

I use:

```
Tasks.find()
```

It seams I need `Tasks.aggregate()` that is not implemented

Comment: According to the docs this should work properly. Did you upgrade your Mongo database to the wired tiger storage? If you don't need to keep any data, doing a `meteor reset` is the quckest way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came to conclusion that $lookup in angular2-meteor would corrupt the data. We used different approach. We store all needed data in all collections.